# Cannot update record with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I've tried everything to get this to work and I know I'm missing something very simple.

I have a method that calls a stored procedure to update a record in a table.

It just so happens that one of the parameters is nullable in the database and the program value for it comes in as an empty string ("") for the `vehicleNo` column in this particular kind of situation.

All the other records get updated except if an empty string comes in and I try and update the record with the stored procedure.

Can someone please point out what I need to add to make the stored procedure or code work correctly?

Below the code, I've tried executing the stored procedure with hard coded values, but neither updates with the `ImageID`.

**Stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPR_UPDATE_IMAGEID] 
    @ticketNo int,
    @vehicleNo varchar(6) = NULL,
    @imageID varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF ((@vehicleNo = '') OR (@vehicleNo IS NULL))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.HH_FuelTkt
            SET Image_ID = @imageID
            WHERE Ticket_No = @ticketNo
              AND Vehicle_No = NULL 
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.HH_FuelTkt
            SET Image_ID = @imageID
            WHERE Ticket_No = @ticketNo
              AND Vehicle_No = @vehicleNo 
    END    END
```

**C# code:**

```
public static bool UpdateData(int ticketNo, string vehicleNo, string imageID)
{
    int retValue = 0;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HHInboundSqlConnection"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPR_UPDATE_IMAGEID", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketNo", ticketNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleNo", vehicleNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imageID", imageID);

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            retValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    return (retValue > 0);
}
```

**Manual stored procedure execution #1:**

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SPR_UPDATE_IMAGEID]
        @ticketNo = 147058,
        @vehicleNo = N'''''',
        @imageID = N'39084'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

**Manual stored procedure execution #2:**

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SPR_UPDATE_IMAGEID]
        @ticketNo = 147058,
        @vehicleNo = N'NULL',
        @imageID = N'39084'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: this looks wrong 
 IF ((@vehicleNo <> '') OR (@vehicleNo IS NULL))

should it not be @vehicleN0 = ''?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the syntax. I tried removing one part, then another part; ran them separately, and still didn't work.

Comment: dont you want to check if its an empty string OR null?
also, in the second sproc, do you not mean 
@vehicleNo = NULL
rather than the nvarchar value 'NULL'
also, I dont think you should use the N in front of your string literals because that denotes nvarchar and you are using varchars

Comment: Yes, I do want to check if it's an empty string or null. When I run the second SPROC manually, it automatically puts in that value when executed.

Comment: I changed my SPROC around to do positive decision making (see edit), but still doesn't work.

Comment: I manually executed both SPROCS above, and still cannot update the record.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF ((@vehicleNo = '') OR (@vehicleNo IS NULL))
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.HH_FuelTkt
        SET Image_ID = @imageID
        WHERE Ticket_No = @ticketNo
          **AND Vehicle_No = NULL** 
END
```

change the

```
AND Vehicle_No = NULL
```

to

```
AND Vehicle_No IS NULL
```

Normally on SQL check nullable value we use IS NULL instead of = NULL

Comment: I agree with @ah_hau. `something = NULL` is a common rookie mistake in SQL code.

Comment: I can't believe I set the statement to "= NULL" instead of "IS NULL". It was a long day... over 12 hours and my brain was fried. I can't remember the last time I made that mistake. Thanks :)